# How to Download a Word File in HTML and Rename It

Tags: javascript, html

This is a bit of a newby question, so forgive me...
I have coded an anchor to retrieve and display a Word document from a document server:

```
<a href="http://docserver/DirectoryPath/File_12345.docx" target="_blank"><img src="DownloadButton.gif"/></a>
```

When the user clicks on the image, the file is returned and the user is asked whether to Open, Save or Save As.

The twist is that I would like to be able to present the user with a different default name for the file in the Save As dialog, such as "File.docx" instead of "File_12345.docx".

I've searched the HTML references to no avail, so I'm guessing it requires a more sophisticated approach.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your docserver to send this header when it serves File_12345.docx:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="File.docx"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition has more information about this header.

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  This won't quite work for our setup as the server doesn't know the required default name, but this is useful information which I might be able to incorporate in an alternative solution.

Comment: JohnR Perhaps you could pass that information in the link's query string, such as by appending ”?downloadname=File.docx”, then having the server parse and use that.